# Prove that a proper subgroup of a $p$-group never equals its normalizer.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^{n}$, where $p$ is prime. 
Let $H$ be a proper subgroup. We define its normalizer $$N = \lbrace g \in G, gHg^{-1} = H\rbrace$$
I want to show that $H \neq N$.

For that, I'm trying to use the multiplication action of $H$ on $G/H$.

If $|G.xH| = 1$, then $x \in N$. So I'm looking for $x \not \in H$ such that  $|G.xH| = 1$. What can I do from here ?

I may have an idea but I'm not sure how to conclude :

Let $F = \lbrace xH \in G/H, G.xH = \lbrace xH \rbrace \rbrace$, so $|F|$ is the number of orbits that have cardinality $1$. If I can show that |F| > 1 then it's over. $H$ lies in $F$, so let's suppose $|F| = 1$ and we should find a contradiction.

I'ts not hard to prove that $$|F| \equiv |G/H| \pmod p$$ so with our hypothesis $$|G/H| \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
But how do we conclude from here ?

Comment: Hint: Alternatively, split into whether the subgroup contains the center or not. If it does not, it should be easy. If it does, quotient by the center and see what happens.

Comment: You need to show that $|F| > |\{H\}| = 1$, not $|F| > |H|$, as $F$ is a set of cosets ($H$ being one of the cosets).

Comment: That's totally right !! So we have $|G/H| \equiv 1 \pmod p$... I guess it's absurd as $|G/H|$ must be equal to $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ ... but how do you prove that ?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : thanks for your answer. I'm sure what you're saying works, but I'd really like to conclude with my approach :)

Comment: Do you know that $|G/H| = 0 \bmod p$? (reason: $H$ is a proper subgroup of a $p$-group.) What can you conclude then from knowing $|F| = 0\bmod p$ and $|F|\ge 1$?

Comment: G is a nilpotent group, so...

Answer (score 1):

I give an alternating proof without using the group action. Let $T$ be a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ with $[T:H]=p$ (you have to prove that such a subgroup exists). Then $H$ is maximal subgroups of the $p$-group $T$. Therefore $H \triangleleft T$ (this also needs a short proof). Hence $T \subseteq N$.

Comment: Hmmm I'm note sure if it works... I don't see how you can prove that $T$ exists (it doesn't if $H$ is maximal), and I think that to prove $H \triangleleft T$, you need to use the normalizer of $H$... Or I'm totally wrong.

Comment: Every maximal subgroup in a $p$-group is normal.  So in case $H$ is maximal you can take $T = G$.  That $T$ exists is an easy consequent of the fact that for a $p$-group of order $p^k$ we have chain of normal subgroups $N_0 < ... < N_k$ with $|N_i|=p^i$.

Comment: can you show:
1.such a subgroup exists
2. $H \triangleleft T$
I am not quite sure how to show it.